# Stripe element disabled

Tags: angularjs

I have used stripe element to get credit card information in my project and my website contains https url . Previously stripe element works fine but from few days it is not and it makes all the stripe element disabled.

Comment: you getting an error?

Comment: Yes..
Error ::
Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided does not match the recipient window’s origin .